# Tell amounts of a table column and put that amount as the top collspan

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible I check the number of columns in a table that exists and assign it to the top of that table colspan?

**[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/JoaoFelipePego/3eVRy/)**

```
document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">')
document.write('<thead><tr><th colspan="2"> HEAD GRID </th></tr></thead>')

for(i = 0; i < 13; i++){
   document.write('<tr>')
   document.write('<td>row ' + i + ', column 0</td>')
   document.write('<td>row ' + i + ', column 1</td>')
   document.write('<td>row ' + i + ', column 2</td>')
   document.write('</tr>')
}

document.write('</table>')
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: If you are the one creating the table, surely you already know how many columns you're going to create?

Comment: @user1578653 not always.

Comment: @pmandell I can not calculate the amount of columns to start trying something :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an id on your table, e.g.

```
<table id="mytable" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
  <thead><tr><th colspan="2"> HEAD GRID </th></tr></thead>
  <tr>
    <td>row 0, column 0</td>
    <td>row 0, column 1</td>
    <td>row 0, column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 1, column 0</td>
    <td>row 2, column 1</td>
    <td>row 3, column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- etc. -->
</table>
```

and assuming jQuery (since it's in your tags):

```
var maxCols = 1;

// look at each row in the table
//
$('#mytable tr').each(
  function() {
    // grab the count of columns in this row
    //
    var cols = $(this).children('td').length;

    if (cols > maxCols)
      maxCols = cols;
  }
);

// set `colspan` on our header, assuming a single `th` as in
// your example
//
$('#mytable th').attr('colspan', maxCols);
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/boksc